# How to detect scroll down on a touch device using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, events, touch

I have a infinite scroll method that gets called like so:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize load', function() {
    // execute infinite scroll method
});
```

So it gets executed under the following events:

```
scroll
resize 
load
```

But it doesn't work in iphone (and possible other touch devices).

This is a responsive site for which I have no need to use jQuery mobile or the like. I tried to use a standalone plugin:

http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

But this plugin and others have to be called like so:

```
$(window).touchwipe({
     wipeDown: function() {
        // execute infinite scroll method
     }
});
```

but this means I have to have 2 versions of my code. I am looking for something that I can simply add to my existing code:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize load NEW_EVENT_HERE', function() {
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could have them call the same function.

```
var infiniteScrollMethod=function() {
      // execute infinite scroll method
}
$(window).on('scroll resize load', infiniteScrollMethod).touchwipe({
    wipeDown: infiniteScrollMethod
});
```